# Computer started shutting down on its own

Tags: windows-10, laptop, shutdown

Recently my windows 10 laptop started randomly shutting down on its own. It would be working fine, suddently screen off, and 2 seconds later shut down.
It doesnt seem very consistent and related to heat, since it sometimes shuts down when its not really doing much, and on other occasions I have been able to play intensive games for quite a while, with not much issues. Also the intervals between shutdowns are not consistent.

It should also not be related to battery, since it is plugged in all the time.

It is NOT preceeded by a BSOD either, and BlueScreenView does not show any new events. The Event viewer does have some logs during startup which say that the previous shutdown was unexpected.

One related change that I can think of is until recently i used the laptop plugged to a monitor and its own display unused, and now I am using it with its inbuilt display on.

Heating related, about a couple weeks back, I did clean the fan vents and redo the thermal paste, leading to a drastic reduction in fan speed.

Any way of debugging or tracking what causes the shutdown?

Comment: Do you get any "You are about to be signed off" message before it shuts down? How often does it happen (once a day, once a month?)

Comment: Can you update BIOS and the Power Drivers?

Comment: @PMF no warning, just suddenly screen off -> 2 seconds later laptop off.

Comment: @John I did about a month back update the bios to the latest for this model.